# What kind of images does Latex generate?

Tags: equations

Suppose I view a Wikipedia page that has math formulas on it.  They use Latex, with the "math" tag in angle-brackets.
The next step is to send it to my Kindle (Amazon provides users of Chrome with an option to send any webpage to the Kindle).  The result unfortunately shows markup instead of equations.
So I'm trying to understand: do the Latex macros generate images in the webpage?
If so, I should be able to save the webpage to my local PC, and the images would come along too, and then I could send the whole thing to the Kindle (or any tablet) for reading off line.

(I know one solution that would work, I could print the page as a PDF, and then send that to a Kindle or tablet, but PDFs are not ideal for small screens).  Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: latex itself doesn't make any image format but there are many scripts that will take a small latex document and convert the pdf page to a png or some such image. but wikipedia I think mostly uses mathjax these days so isn't using tex at all for rendering maths

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Wikipedia only uses LaTeX _syntax_, it doesn't actually use the LaTeX engine. I suspect Wikipedia stores the maths using MathML, though by default people who view Wikipedia pages with <math> tags see PNG images. If you can get the images onto your Kindle, it might work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about MathML